# Problem wuth Ruby threads

Tags: ruby, multithreading, xmpp

I write a [simple bot](http://pastebin.com/qfkpMSce) using "SimpleMUCClient". But got error: app.rb:73:in `stop': deadlock detected (fatal)
from app.rb:73:in`'. How to fix it?

Comment: How to fix it? **Don't cause a deadlock.** (You need to provide a lot more information before this becomes a real question...)

Comment: Can you give me a sample code?

Comment: No, I really can't. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the code you're running is executed in another thread. That particular thread is then joined (meaning Ruby waits for it to finish upon exiting the script) using `Thread.join()`. Calling `Thread.stop()` while also calling `.join()` is most likely the cause of the deadlock. Having said that you should following the guides of StackOverflow regarding how to ask questions properly, since you haven't done so I've down voted your question.

Joining a thread while still calling `Thread.stop` can be done as following:

```
th = Thread.new do
  Thread.stop
end

if th.status === 'sleep'
  th.run
else
  th.join
end
```

It's not the cleanest way but it works. Also, if you want to actually terminate a thread you'll have to call `Thread.exit` instead.

Comment: with your code, I also got app.rb:79:in `join': deadlock detected (fatal)
 from app.rb:79:in `<main>'

Comment: Then there's most likely something going on outside of the code you've posted or something else is causing the deadlock.